# Get count of elements of two dimensional array by given first index

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have array defined like this :

```
List<DocumentFields>[,] dummyArray = new List<DocumentFields>[8,8];
```

It takes records from the database. I need to prepare this array for showing in a asp.net mvc3 view so i iterate it the standard way :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Header.GetLength(0); i++)
              {
                    for (int j = 0; j < ViewBag.Header.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
```

But I realized that in fact for the second iteration I don't need the Length but the count of the elements that are actually there. So instead of `ViewBag.Header.GetLength(1)` I need this:

```
ViewBag.Header.Get_Count_Of_The_Elements_For_The_Second_Index
```

I couldn't find a property that do this right away. Maybe some way of using `Length` or something... Dunno...

Comment: What type is `ViewBag.Header`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to use a jagged array instead of a multidimensional array?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth ViewBag.Header = dummyArray;

Comment: @m-y Never user jagged array. Have to look up for this. Is it possible to provide example?

Comment: @m-y Yeah, It seems that Jagged array is what I need. If you want give it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your dummyArray  is a two-dimensional array of lists. To get list size you can use `dummyArray[i,j].Count` in your inner loop.

Comment: I think this will return the elements in the List or I'm mistaken?

Comment: Yep. If you want to return the size of the array's second dimension, then keep in mind that it is constant and independent of the size of first dimension, which is also constant. GetLength(dimension_number) should do just fine.